# Python Library "Click" pass arguments to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I am using the click library and I have a function "agent_diff" that takes in three arguments...and I would like to take in arguments from the CLI and pass that into my function. But I am not entirely sure how to pass those values into "agent_diff". Here is the current code that I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from sys import path
path.append(os.getcwd())
from src.main.scripts.bitbucket import *
import click




@click.command()
@click.argument('arg')
@click.option('--repository')
@click.option('tag1')
@click.option('tag2')

def main(arg):
    print(os.path.expanduser("~"))

    if arg.upper() == 'ORB-LIST':
        print('Printing List of Orbs:')
        orb_list()
    if arg.upper() == 'AGENT-LIST':
        print('Printing List of Agents:')
        agent_list()
    if arg.upper() == 'AGENT-DIFF':
        agent_diff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any insight would be wonderful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The click arguments and options must correspond to the arguments of the function. See the example below.

```py
@click.command()
@click.argument('arg')
@click.option('--repository')
@click.option('tag1')
@click.option('tag2')
def main(arg, repository, tag1, tag2):
    # do stuff...
    pass
```

The order of the arguments does not matter.